# Magento 2: How to get All Active Categories in Custom Module Admin Form Dropdown?

Tags: magento2, category, grid, uicomponent

Here is my form `UI component` code:

```
<field name="category_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Allsection\Source\Categories</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Field Label</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">allsection</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_id</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Here is my source code file `Model\Allsection\Source`:

```
<?php

namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Allsection\Source;

class Categories implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{    
    protected $_categories;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collection)
    {
        $this->_categories = $collection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {    
        $collection = $this->_categories->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $itemArray = array('value' => '', 'label' => '--Please Select--');
        $options = [];
        $options = $itemArray;
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $options[] = ['value' => $category->getId(), 'label' => $category->getName()];
        }
        return $options;
    }    
}    

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use below code:**

```
<field name="category_id" sortOrder="20" formElement="select">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Categry</label>
            <dataScope>category_id</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class=>Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Allsection\Source\Categories"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

**And Select  Source Class:**

```
<?php
namespace Vrinsoft\Appscreens\Model\Allsection\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Categories implements  OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ){
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $categories = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('is_active', 1)
            ->addFieldToSelect('is_active')->addFieldToSelect('name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id');
        $options[] = array('value' => '', 'label' => '--Please Select--');
        foreach ($categories as $category){
            $options[] = [
                'value' => $category->getEntityId(),
                'label' => $category->getName(),
            ];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much that was working ..

Comment: hello sir one more issued in my other code recently i added new question can you please help me